# Django - getting display value from ModelChoiceField within template

Tags: python, html, django

So I have a template as follows:

```
<input class="form-control" id="{{ form.date.auto_id }}" name="{{ form.date.html_name }}" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="{{ form.date.value }}">
```

The field it is rendering from is a ModelChoiceField:

```
class DateChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.date.strftime("%A %d. %B %Y")
```

How can I get the actual display value in the text field instead of just the primary key?

Comment: can you elaborate ur question a bit more.